# What is this measure of error?

Tags: binomial-distribution, error

I'm reading through someone else's code for plotting the results of a psychology experiment, and (according to the code comments) they calculate the accuracy error of their behavioral paradigm as follows:

$\textit{accuracy error} = \sqrt{\frac{(\textit{accuracy}) (1-\textit{accuracy})}{\textit{total trials}}}$

It's output seems to be very similar to the original accuracy. What is this? Is this some sort of multiple comparison correction? Why would they do this?

Comment: This estimates the standard error of the "accuracy" as measured from "total trials" draws from a Bernoulli variable.

Comment: @whuber - Why not just use `number correct / total trials` like everywhere else?

Comment: Because they're not actually estimating accuracy but the standard error.  If they're actually estimating accuracy this way it's just WRONG. Check the values, are there any over 0.5?  If there are then this isn't the accuracy estimate equation.

Comment: If the result seems similar to the input, it's only a coincidence.  The equation is just a reworded formula for the standard error of a proportion, as is shown halfway down at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error

Comment: If the output seems similar to the accuracy, that means the experiment is unreliable, which worrying and the whole point of the exercise. This only happens when accuracy is low and number of trials is small.

Comment: @whuber, @rolando2 Make answers, not comments (-;

Comment: Why _are_ there so many near-answers in the comments, but no actual answers?  I guess I'll take a stab below.

Comment: @Karl There was [some discussion of this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers) a few months ago.  For many reasons, it is indeed helpful to create full-fledged replies to questions whose answers may be buried in comments.  Thank you for taking this on, and welcome to our site!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing me to the relevant discussion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the estimated accuracy is number correct / total trials in some set of independent trials, the formula you give would be the standard error of the estimated accuracy.  "Accuracy error" is not unreasonable, but I would just call it the standard error of the estimate.

[*poking around in the unanswered questions*]